# How to read from a file and in the file display only the lines starting with integers

Tags: java

I want to read from a file and display it in a combo box and it must show only lines starting with numbers

The txt

```
 11 Fufu high school
       Brie 
        Enjoy
         Yoyo
12 TLT high school
     High
     Right
     Pupu
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So from your description, you need a way to read characters from a file, filter them out such that lines which are showing numbers are showing, and then display this to a combo box.

To begin, you will need a class called BufferedReader. An example of the use can be seen below

```
String filename = "yourFileName"
BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))
String line = bw.read()
```

Once the BufferedReader is created, you can read the lines of text from file and now the only thing left to do before pushing these strings to the combobox is to filter out the lines you do not want. Since we do not know the formatting of the file you have, the next best thing is to point you towards the String class api which can be used to filter the string however you need it to be done

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Once the formatting has been done, you can add an item to the combobox (assuming you are using a JComboBox from swing) using the method addItem()